# Clicking on a button to generate results using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am making an app. I would like that when I click on the button, `btnCalculating`, the results would appear at the bottom. However, right now when I clicked on the button, nothing is appearing. My codes are below as shown. Is there anyway to solve this problem? Thank you in advance! :)

```js
(function () {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnCalculating").bind("click", function () {
      Calculating();
    });
  });

  function Calculating() {;
    var conversioning;
    conversioning = $("[name=conversioning]:checked").val();
    $("#Converting").append("You are converting " + conversioning);
  };
});
```

```html
<div class="ui-block">
  <input type="button" id="btnCalculating" value="Calculate" />
</div>                   
<div id="Converting"></div>
```

Comment: The problem is you never call you anonymous outside function, add a `()` before the last `;` to call it.

Comment: (function () {  and  $(document).ready(function () { both are same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using JQ ready shorthand wrong. Your code formatted:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#btnCalculating").bind("click", function () {
        Calculating();
    });


    function Calculating() {
        var conversioning;
        conversioning = $("[name=conversioning]:checked").val();
        $("#Converting").empty();
        $("#Converting").append("You are converting " + conversioning);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-block"><input type="button" id="btnCalculating" value="Calculate" /></div>  

<div id="Converting"></div>
```

Comment: hello! the code is now running the way I want it to be. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @yxlxn No problem happy to help, you should choose the answer that helped you so others can know this problem is solved.

Comment: Will do! I have another question, if i repeatedly press the button, it would generate the results again and again. Is there anyway to fix it so that no matter how many times i press it, it would not generate more of it?

Comment: @yxlxn Yes there is with JQ `empty` method I've edited my snippet now it works like you want.

Comment: ah yes it is indeed! Thank you so much! :) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is a `;` after the bracket. Try to remove it, so you have this.
Did you check for error's in the console? I think this should fix it.

```
function Calculating() {
     var conversioning;
     conversioning = $("[name=conversioning]:checked").val();
     $("#Converting").append("You are converting " + conversioning);
 };
```

Comment: Hello! I have removed the ; and it is still not working sadly. Neither were there any errors. :(

Comment: Then this wasn't the problem. But the answer above seems to be working perfect and fixes your problem!

Comment: Yep it did. Thank you so much for spending your time trying to help me. :)